# Guardar datos específicos con python y json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

quiero guardar en un nuevo archivo Json todo lo que este en una fecha especifica, en este json hay datos de 2021-04-16 y 2021-04-20 , quisiera guardar todo lo que este en fechas especificas

no solo el valor data: si no todo el contenido o todas las fechas que coincidan con 2021-04-20 con un script python.

para tratar de resolver eso cree un sub-modulo.py que contiene la libreria datatime y me trae el dia actual, luego de guardar esta fecha abro el json y tomo el valor data: para tener la fecha y con un if tratar de buscar si la fecha coincide con el dia actual, si es asi que me guarde todo lo que tenga dentro del json con esa fecha.

teniendo en cuenta que hay diferentes fechas en el json

agradezco su colaboracion.

archivo json

```
[{
  "_": "Message",
  "id": 3,
  "peer_id": {
    "_": "PeerChannel",
    "channel_id": 1401547083
  },
  "date": "2021-04-20T21:26:39+00:00",
  "message": "Team rose para prueba Json 2",
  "out": true,
  "mentioned": false,
  "media_unread": false,
  "silent": false,
  "post": false,
  "from_scheduled": false,
  "legacy": false,
  "edit_hide": false,
  "pinned": false,
  "from_id": {
    "_": "PeerUser",
    "user_id": 803543561
  },
  "fwd_from": null,
  "via_bot_id": null,
  "reply_to": null,
  "media": null,
  "reply_markup": null,
  "entities": [],
  "views": null,
  "forwards": null,
  "replies": {
    "_": "MessageReplies",
    "replies": 0,
    "replies_pts": 4,
    "comments": false,
    "recent_repliers": [],
    "channel_id": null,
    "max_id": null,
    "read_max_id": null
  },
  "edit_date": null,
  "post_author": null,
  "grouped_id": null,
  "restriction_reason": [],
  "ttl_period": null
}, {
  "_": "Message",
  "id": 2,
  "peer_id": {
    "_": "PeerChannel",
    "channel_id": 1401547083
  },
  "date": "2021-04-16T22:48:04+00:00",
  "message": "team de prueba para json",
  "out": true,
  "mentioned": false,
  "media_unread": false,
  "silent": false,
  "post": false,
  "from_scheduled": false,
  "legacy": false,
  "edit_hide": false,
  "pinned": false,
  "from_id": {
    "_": "PeerUser",
    "user_id": 803543561
  },
  "fwd_from": null,
  "via_bot_id": null,
  "reply_to": null,
  "media": null,
  "reply_markup": null,
  "entities": [],
  "views": null,
  "forwards": null,
  "replies": {
    "_": "MessageReplies",
    "replies": 0,
    "replies_pts": 4,
    "comments": false,
    "recent_repliers": [],
    "channel_id": null,
    "max_id": null,
    "read_max_id": null
  },
  "edit_date": null,
  "post_author": null,
  "grouped_id": null,
  "restriction_reason": [],
  "ttl_period": null
}, {
  "_": "MessageService",
  "id": 1,
  "peer_id": {
    "_": "PeerChannel",
    "channel_id": 1401547083
  },
  "date": "2021-04-16T01:45:43+00:00",
  "action": {
    "_": "MessageActionChannelMigrateFrom",
    "title": "teamrose",
    "chat_id": 592408705
  },
  "out": true,
  "mentioned": false,
  "media_unread": false,
  "silent": false,
  "post": false,
  "legacy": false,
  "from_id": null,
  "reply_to": null,
  "ttl_period": null
}]
```

este es el modulo que cree para traer todo lo que este en el json respecto al dia actual.

```
import json
from glob import glob
from datetime import datetime

def load_data():

    ficheros_json = glob('/home/logs/data/*.json')

    for nombre_fichero in ficheros_json:

        with open(nombre_fichero) as contenido:
            resultados = json.load(contenido)

            for resultado in resultados:

                date = datetime.now()
                data_f = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

                date_json = resultado.get('date')
                value = date_json.split("T")
                data_f_json = value[0]

                if data_f_json == data_f:

                    data_message = (resultado.get('date'))

                    f =  open('log.messages.data','a')
                    f.write(str(data_message))
                    f.close()

load_data()
```

dentro de este modulo lo que hice fue tener una variable **data_f** con el dia actual, luego separar con la funcion split() el **"date": "2021-04-16T01:45:43+00:00",** que esta en el archivo json, luego comparo si hay datos recientes con un if, no se como traer todo lo que este en el json que coincida con el dia actual y que me lo guarde, ya sea en otro json o en cualquier archivo (.txt. .data  .log) agradezco su ayuda, gracias

Comment: Hola @DaveNISC , recuerda mostrar un ejemplo de lo que ya haz intentado, y aclarar cual parte no funciona. Ejemplo de outputs deseados aun mejor. Sin pena muestra el código ;)

Comment: hola, es que trate de subir el modulo python  que trate de crear pero en esta pagina me dice que hay mas codigo que texto y me sale error, no me deja publicar por eso lo borre :S